# deploy laravel sail on digitalocean permissions error

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, laravel-sail

I installed Laravel Sail locally (mac os) and it works perfectly.

When I tried to deploy it in DigitalOcean, I've got an infinite permissions errors.

So, I created a new droplet with docker installed on it by DigitalCcean

(marketplace applications -> docker -> [**Version** 19.03.12, **OS** Ubuntu 20.04]),

and here is what I did

1 - in terminal ~ directory, I ran `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`, it installed everything as expected.

2 - I created an alias `alias sail='./vendor/bin/sail'`

3 - After it finished, I cd into "example-app" directory and run the command `sail up -d` and it works fine and all processes and services are up and running.

4 - go to browser and try to open the website by IP, I’ve got this error ***The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied***

I tried to run `sail composer update`, I got this error ***file_put_contents(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/installed.json): Failed to open stream: Permission denied***

The only way to make it work is running `chmod -R 777 example-app`
**I know this is not right**, so I need help here to make it work **the best and correct way**

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to let the code be owned by the correct user and group. You can put the user and group in your .env as [WWWUSER](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/4e43fe7096d106a2cdfc758f6122b67539ff219d/runtimes/8.1/start-container) and [WWWGROUP](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile#L49) respectively.
Then if needed, use `chown` in your container to give this user ownership. E.g.

`chown -R <wwwuser>:<wwwgroup> /var/www/html`

https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/docker-compose.stub#L21

---

Please note that sail is **not meant for production**